# How to set the language a plain text is read as in Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, syntax-highlighting

I've been using Notepad++ for editing CSS, and for just plain text. In Notepad++ I can paste a block of text and specify if I want the file to be highlighted as HTML, CSS, etc.

How do I set the language that Visual Studio will use to interpret a block of text I pasted from my clipboard? What about when I open a plain TXT file?

Am I using the wrong tool for the job? I've been hearing about "Visual Studio Code". Is that what I should use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, *Visual Studio* works with "Project". It is designed to work with the relevant files for the project, and it will recognize them according to the extension.

In Visual Studio, you can override the default config for the file extension with [this docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-file-extension). This configuration will work against all files with this extension, but not against a specific file.

I guess there are plugins that can help on the subject, but as you said, *Visual Studio Code* is more like a **file editor** like *Notepad++*, with very powerful plugins and capabilities. So yes, in case you want an enhanced **Notepad++**, you need to use the *Visual Studio Code* and not the *Visual Studio*.

Comment: so there is no way to force it to interpret a file as a certain language besides changing the file's extension?

Comment: @JorgeLuque I edited my answer. You can force Visual Studio by file extension

Answer (score 1):

After using both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code I can confidently tell you VS Code is so much swifter to open and use while also being very easy to navigate.

VS Code automatically detects the language of your code but you can also switch languages by clicking on the existing language at the bottom.

I highly recommend you use it: https://code.visualstudio.com/